# Simple CMD argument throught VBScript

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

Its been a while...

I have the command line arg:

```
xml sel -t  -v "computer/general/name" nsk1501901173m.xml > test.txt
```

that produces the results I want in the text document specified but I need to run it through a VBScript and for the life of me I cannot figure it out... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [`WScript.Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object to execute the app and the [`cmd /c`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) (command shell with the /C parameter) before to pass your app arguments , check this sample

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "cmd /c xml sel -t  -v ""computer/general/name"" nsk1501901173m.xml > test.txt",1,true
```

Remember which script must be executed from the same location where the xml.exe app is located or even better add the location of xml.exe app to the `PATH`